# Flutter Disable only one side swipe

Tags: flutter, tabs

I have a `TabBar` with 4 tabs.

I want to disable swiping only when tab with index 2 is showing so that user cant see the content of the  tab with index 3.

Note: using `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` will disable swipe on all tabs and that is **NOT** the desired result. I need the user to be able to swipe among other tabs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TabController` and listening that when index is 2, when index is 2 you shouldn't change tab index to 2